# Why user is logging out after refresh the page? React/Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux

As in the title - the user is logging out when I reload the page in my React/Redux application. I store the token in localStorage but it doesn't work so there is probably any mistake. The token should be stored when the user logs in. Logging out works correctly. Here is my code:

auth.js (reducers directory - Redux):

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, LOGOUT_SUCCESS, REGISTER_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAIL } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  isLoading: false,
  isRegistered: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false,
        isRegistered: true
      }
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
      }
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Response from the server when the user logs in:
[image]

Comment: You should also share whenever you are using the reducers actions, maybe your persistance code is not working as it should. Or maybe you are doing a wrong call to an action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't really know how you check if there is a logged in user, but when you refresh the page, the store doesn't get automatically filled. So maybe you should add something like this if you check authentication state against `isAuthenticated` :

```
const initialState = {
   token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
   isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false, // or just !!localStorage.getItem('token')
   isLoading: false,
   isRegistered: false
}
```

or use some function to check localStorage and update the store accordingly.

Comment: Glad it helped you! :-)

Comment: This is the way!

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing here, but it looks like your `initialState.isAuthenticated` is always `null`,  you need to verify against the `token` from the `localStorage`

Answer (score 1):

The approach of Martial Anouman is true, but for the long term I think you can **save redux store to the localStorage** as well, so if user refreshes the page, the redux state will be saved to the localStorage and the initial state values will not be gone after refresh. I use `redux-persist` library, you can [take a look at their github](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for the implementation

Comment: Thanks, I will check this solution